# Test class giving Error-Attempt to de-reference a null object for Mapping

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am trying to develop Custom Mapping when I convert "Application(Custom Object)" , it gets converted into "Account" "Contact" and "Loan(Custom Object)" . My functionality is working pretty well but in my Test class it is giving error

> Attempt to de-reference a null
>   objectClass.ApplicationMappingController.Convert: line 281, column 1
>   Class.ApplicationMappingController_TC.ApplicationMappingControllerMeth:
>   line 51, column 1

Here is my code for Application Mapping Controller

```
 public pagereference Convert()
    {   


        PageReference pageRef;
        list<Enrollment_Mapping__c> lstEnrollment_Mapping = [Select Id, Source_field__c, source_object__c, Target_field__c, target_object__c from Enrollment_Mapping__c order by target_object__c LIMIT 1000];

        if(lstEnrollment_Mapping.size() == 0) 
        {
            pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/ApplicationMapping');
            pageRef.setRedirect(true);
            return pageRef;
        }

        String SOQL = 'Select RecordType.Name,IsConverted__c,';
        for(Enrollment_Mapping__c loopvar : lstEnrollment_Mapping)
            SOQL = SOQL + loopvar.Source_Field__c + ',';

        if(!(SOQl.indexOfIgnoreCase('First_Name__c') > 0)) SOQL += 'First_Name__c,';
        if(!(SOQl.indexOfIgnoreCase('Last_Name__c') > 0)) SOQL += 'Last_Name__c,';

        //SOQL = SOQL.substring(0, SOQL.length()-2);
        SOQL = SOQL.removeEnd(',');
        SOQl += ' From Application__c where Id= \''+ appObj.Id + '\'';
        System.debug('--SOQL-- : ' +SOQL);

        try
        {
            appObj = database.query(SOQL);
            appObj.IsConverted__c = true;
            appObj.Merchant_cash_Application_Status__c='Qualified';
            system.debug('appObj======++++'+appObj);
            update appObj;
        }
        catch(QueryException e) 
        {
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.Info,'Something is wrong. Please check mapping'));
        }


        Id RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Client').getRecordTypeId();            
        Account AnewObj = new Account();  
        AnewObj.Name = appObj.First_Name__c + ' ' + appObj.Last_Name__c;
        AnewObj.RecordTypeId = RecordTypeId;
        for(Enrollment_Mapping__c loopvar : lstEnrollment_Mapping)
        {   
            if(loopvar.Target_Object__c == 'Account')
                AnewObj.put(loopvar.target_field__c, appObj.get(loopvar.source_field__c));

        }
        insert AnewObj;

        //pageRef = new PageReference('/'+newObj.Id);

        RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Contact.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Client Contact').getRecordTypeId();
        Contact CnewObj = new Contact(); 
        CnewObj.FirstName = appObj.First_Name__c;
        CnewObj.LastName = appObj.Last_Name__c;
        CnewObj.AccountId = AnewObj.Id;
        CnewObj.RecordTypeId = RecordTypeId;
        for(Enrollment_Mapping__c loopvar : lstEnrollment_Mapping) 
        {   
            if(loopvar.Target_Object__c == 'Contact')
                CnewObj.put(loopvar.target_field__c, appObj.get(loopvar.source_field__c)); 
        }
        insert CnewObj;


/*error on this line*/ RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.loan__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get(appObj.RecordType.Name).getRecordTypeId();
        system.debug('******************'+RecordTypeId);

        Loan__c LnewObj = new Loan__c(); 
        LnewObj.Name = appObj.First_Name__c + ' ' + appObj.Last_Name__c;
        LnewObj.RecordTypeId = RecordTypeId;
        LnewObj.Account__c = AnewObj.id;
        for(Enrollment_Mapping__c loopvar : lstEnrollment_Mapping)
        {   
            if(loopvar.Target_Object__c == 'Loan__c')
                LnewObj.put(loopvar.target_field__c, appObj.get(loopvar.source_field__c)); 
        }
        insert LnewObj;


        String Result = 'Account : <a href="\\' + AnewObj.id + '">'+AnewObj.Name +'</a> <br/>';
        Result += 'Contact : <a href="\\' + CnewObj.id + '">'+CnewObj.FirstName + ' ' + CnewObj.LastName +'</a> <br/>';
        Result += 'Loan : <a href="\\' + LnewObj.id + '">'+ LnewObj.Name +'</a>.';
        ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.Info, Result)); 




        pageRef = new PageReference('/'+ LnewObj.id);
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        return pageRef;
    }

    public pagereference ChangeMapping()
    {
        System.debug('--IN--');
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/ApplicationMapping');
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        return pageRef;
    }
    public pagereference refreshPicklist(){
        return null;
    }

    public List<SelectOption> sortSelectOptions(List<SelectOption> sortingList) {
        for (Integer i =0; i < sortingList.size(); i++) {
            for (Integer j = i; j > 0; j--) {
                if (sortingList[j-1].getLabel() > sortingList[j].getLabel()){
                    SelectOption temp = sortingList[j];
                    sortingList[j] = sortingList[j-1];
                    sortingList[j-1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        return sortingList;
    }
}
```

Test Class

```
@isTest(seeAllData=true)
public class ApplicationMappingController_TC
{
     public static testMethod void ApplicationMappingControllerMeth(){

        List<Enrollment_Mapping__c> lst=new List<Enrollment_Mapping__c>();

        Enrollment_Mapping__c objEnrollMapping = new Enrollment_Mapping__c();
        objEnrollMapping.source_field__c='Mailing_City__c';
        objEnrollMapping.source_object__c='Application__c';
        objEnrollMapping.target_object__c='Contact';
        objEnrollMapping.target_field__c='Department';
        insert objEnrollMapping;
        lst.add(objEnrollMapping);

        system.assertNotequals(objEnrollMapping.id,null);

        Enrollment_Mapping__c objEnrollMapping1 = new Enrollment_Mapping__c();
        objEnrollMapping1.source_field__c='Name';
        objEnrollMapping1.source_object__c='Application__c';
        objEnrollMapping1.target_object__c='Contact';
        objEnrollMapping1.target_field__c='FirstName';
        insert objEnrollMapping1;
        lst.add(objEnrollMapping1);

        Id devRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Application__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('MCA').getRecordTypeId();

        system.debug('Record Type+++++' + devRecordTypeId); 

        List<RecordType> recordType = [SELECT id,name FROM RecordType WHERE sObjectType='Application__c' AND Name = 'MCA' limit 1];
        Application__c objApp = new Application__c();

        objApp.Last_Name__c = 'Testing';
        objApp.RecordTypeid = recordType[0].id;
        insert objApp;

          Loan__c  objloan = new loan__c();
          objloan.Name='Testing';
          objloan.RecordType.Name='MCA';
          insert objloan;


        /*  List<RecordType> recordTypeLoan = [SELECT id,name FROM RecordType WHERE sObjectType='Loan__c' AND Name = 'MCA' limit 1];
        Loan__c  objloan = new loan__c();
        objloan.Last_Name__c = 'Testing';
        objloan.RecordType.name = recordType[0].name;
        insert objloan;*/


        System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('id',objApp.id);
        ApplicationMappingController controller = new ApplicationMappingController(new ApexPages.StandardController(objApp));
        controller.addRow();
        controller.saveMapping();
        controller.getObj();
        PageReference pageRef = controller.ChangeMapping();
        Pagereference pageRefresh = controller.refreshPicklist();
        controller.Convert();
        controller.lstApplicationLoanMap=lst;
        controller.lstApplicationContactMap=lst;
        controller.lstApplicationAccountMap=lst;
       // controller.lstApplicationLoanMap=objEnrollMapping1;
    }

}
```

Comment: I think that your code is missing the class declaration. Also, can you indicate which ones are these lines: `ApplicationMappingController.Convert: line 281` and `ApplicationMappingController_TC.ApplicationMappingControllerMeth: line 51`

Comment: as best practice, there should be no good reason to use `seeAllData=true`. It will only lead to deployment issues later for you  or your successor. Mock all objects in the test class/method